# Assets\Scripts\Player.cs(19,45): error CS0117: 'Color' does not contain a definition for 'red'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> Assets\Scripts\Player.cs(19,45): error CS0117: 'Color' does not contain a definition for 'red'

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Color = System.Drawing.Color;


public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    public SpriteRenderer[] renderers;

    private void Start() {
        renderers[0].material.color = Color.red;
    }
}
```

Comment: @DavidG While that will solve the error shown in the post, this is not a helpful solution because a `System.Drawing.Color` is not a valid type for assignment to [`SpriteRenderer.material.color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-color.html), which is a `UnityEngine.Color`. So, doing only that will result in another error appearing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unity doesn't use the `System.Drawing.Color` struct. You need to use `UnityEngine.Color` instead.  All you need to do is remove the lines `using Color = System.Drawing.Color;` and `using System.Drawing;` and you will be using the correct `Color` struct, which **does** have a definition for `Color.red`. See below:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    public SpriteRenderer[] renderers;

    private void Start() {
        renderers[0].material.color = Color.red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this solved my problem

Answer (score -1):

Delete the

```
using Color = System.Drawing.Color;
```

The code should be:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

public SpriteRenderer[] renderers;

   private void Start() 
   {
    renderers[0].material.color = Color.red;
   }
}
```

Comment: I removed that and get new error.

`Assets\Scripts\Player.cs(18,30): error CS0104: 'Color' is an ambiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.Color' and 'System.Drawing.Color`

Comment: This isn't enough to solve the problem.